# TCL glob negative match when listing files

Tags: tcl, glob, negation

I have a directory containing some files (e.g.):

```
SASA_AMK12.txt
SASA_AMK13.txt
SASA_AMK5.txt
SASA_AMK9.txt
SASA_ATH10.txt
SASA_PSK.txt
SASA_ProtAMK12.txt
SASA_ProtAMK13.txt
SASA_ProtAMK5.txt
SASA_ProtAMK9.txt
SASA_ProtATH10.txt
SASA_ProtGSK.txt
```

For listing these files I'm using this glob:

```
set SASA_LIG_PROCESSED [lsort [glob -directory "${WORKDIR}/" -type f -tails *{SASA}*]]
```

However, what I want is to negate the match in the glob by excluding from listing all the filenames that contain "Prot" pattern. So, the desired output should be:

```
SASA_AMK12.txt
SASA_AMK13.txt
SASA_AMK5.txt
SASA_AMK9.txt
SASA_ATH10.txt
SASA_PSK.txt
```

I tried already with something like SASA**?!Prot** but it is not working. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it two steps. First use `glob` to get a list of files like you're doing now, and then [`lsearch`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) with the `-not` and `-all` options to filter out the ones you don't want.

```
# set SASA_LIG_PROCESSED [glob -directory "${WORKDIR}/" -type f -tails {*SASA*}]
set files {
    SASA_AMK12.txt
    SASA_AMK13.txt
    SASA_AMK5.txt
    SASA_AMK9.txt
    SASA_ATH10.txt
    SASA_PSK.txt
    SASA_ProtAMK12.txt
    SASA_ProtAMK13.txt
    SASA_ProtAMK5.txt
    SASA_ProtAMK9.txt
    SASA_ProtATH10.txt
    SASA_ProtGSK.txt
    }

set SASA_LIG_PROCESSED [lsort -dictionary [lsearch -all -inline -not $files {*Prot*}]]
puts $SASA_LIG_PROCESSED
# SASA_AMK5.txt SASA_AMK9.txt SASA_AMK12.txt SASA_AMK13.txt SASA_ATH10.txt SASA_PSK.txt
```